# How to display data from database between two selected date

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE date Between '$start_date' and '$end_date' order by date asc") or die(mysql_query);
```

Above mysql query is to get all data in the database between two dates selected by the user. Let say table attendance in my database as shown below

```
2009-07-01    3
2009-07-03    4
2009-07-04    5
2009-07-06    7
2009-07-07    6
2009-07-10    8
```

1. if the $start_date = "2009-07-01" and $end_date = "2009-07-10", it will display all the data between two selected dates

   ```
   2009-07-01    3
   2009-07-03    4
   2009-07-04    5
   2009-07-06    7
   2009-07-07    6
   2009-07-10    8
   ```

( I noticed that this is successful because, both dates are exist in the database).

1. if the $start_date = "2009-07-02" and $end_date = "2009-07-09", what i expected it to be displayed is

   ```
   2009-07-03    4
   2009-07-04    5
   2009-07-06    7
   2009-07-07    6
   ```

Unfortunately, the output never goes out like what I've expected. This is happened because both dates doesn't exist in the database. I know that something wrong with my query. It would be great if someone can help me to figure it out. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: So what does get output in your in your final case? Nothing? Everything?

Comment: Nothing.... @andrewsi

Comment: What happens if you have a start date of 2009-07-01 and an end date of 2009-07-09? And what is the definition of `date` in your database table?

Comment: I got an error that says variable for date 2009-07-09 ($end_date) is undefined.  column name:date ;  data types: date; @andrewsi

Comment: Does your working query return `2009-07-26    7`? That definitely shouldn't be returned based on your query.

Comment: Sorry! I've edited the quest. I wanted to write 2009-07-06. @andrewsi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL compare DATE string with string from DATETIME field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758486/mysql-compare-date-string-with-string-from-datetime-field)

Answer (score -1):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE DATE(date) Between '$start_date' and '$end_date' order by date asc") or die(mysql_query);
```

OR

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE DATE(date) >='$start_date' and DATE(date) <='$end_date' order by date asc") or die(mysql_query);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried both of it. But Still got the same error message.

Comment: It said that variable for $start_date and $end_date are undefined if both selected date are not in the database.

Comment: $start_date and $end_date undefined its not related to database. its php error. Can just echo those dates before the sql query

echo $start_date ."----". $end_date;

Comment: Please check part where assign value to $start_date varibale

Comment: $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE DATE(date) >='2009-07-02' and DATE(date) <='2009-07-10' order by date asc") or die(mysql_query);