# LARAVEL Update data using array

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, sql-update

i wanna update my data using array, but its error 'cause im using "like" query while finding the data. This is the code.

```
$pin = 10590;
$datetime = "2017-08-29 15:05:00";
$date = explode(' ', $datetime);
Attendance::where('user_id', $pin)->where('datetime_in', 'like', '%' . $date[0] . '%')->update([
   'datetime_out' => $datetime,
   'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d')
]);
```

any solutions ?? Thanks.

Comment: There should not be an error. can you add detailed output of debugger?

Comment: @Buglinjo the server is down right now so i cant show the output, but if i run the code in mysql, the error is like this
    `Incorrect datetime value: '%2017-08-29%' for column 'datetime_in'`

Comment: You should be using like filter on varchar or text not datetime. On datetime simply use =

Comment: @Buglinjo like this?
`UPDATE attendance SET datetime_out="2017-08-29 15:06:00" WHERE user_id = 201037917001 AND datetime_in = "2017-08-29";`

Comment: Like this:
`Attendance::where('user_id', $pin)->where('datetime_in', '=', $date[0])->update([
   'datetime_out' => $datetime,
   'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d')
]);`

Comment: @Buglinjo ok, i'll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare a datetime column using `like`.

Comparing using `=`, as suggested in the comments will also not yield the desired result, interpolating `2017-08-29` to `2017-08-29 00:00:00` (see [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17169859/3919281)).

**1. Cast column to DATE**

Assuming you're using MySQL, you can cast the type of the queried column to `DATE` like this:

```
$query->whereRaw('DATE(datetime_in) = ?', [$day])…
```

*PostgreSQL:*

```
$query->whereRaw('datetime_in::date = ?', [$day])…
```

**2. WHERE BETWEEN**

Alternatively, you can query using `whereBetween` and specify start end end of day as time by using [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/carbon).

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$startOfDay = new Carbon($datetime)->startOfDay();
$endOfDay = new Carbon($datetime)->endOfDay();

$query->whereBetween('datetime_in', [$startOfDay, $endOfDay])…
```