# String to Datetime cast in Where clause Mysql and Impala

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a mysql table which have datetime stored as string. I want to get the rows from the table with the time range provided.

My table  looks like:

```
datetime                   plugin_name
2017-11-12T00:44:48.530000  testng
2017-11-12T00:44:48.529000  testng
2017-11-12T00:46:22.668000  testng
2017-11-12T00:46:22.666000  testng
2017-11-12T01:00:16.338000  ntf-test
```

Here column `datetime` has type as `String`.I have tried with this query

```
select `datetime`, plugin_name  
from plugin_names 
where datetime(`datetime`) > '2017-06-29T06:16:49.426000' 
and DATETIME(`datetime`) < '2017-06-29T06:16:49.314000'
```

But I am getting error as:

```
Encountered: DATETIME
Expected: CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER
```

I tried following this: [MySQL compare DATE string with string from DATETIME field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758486/mysql-compare-date-string-with-string-from-datetime-field)

I am using Impala for distributed Mysql database
Anyone has idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is this query to be executed in MySQL? or Impala? please add that information as tags. For Impala use this ref: [**TIMESTAMP Data Type**](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_timestamp.html#timestamp)

Comment: By the way `datetime` as a column name is going to be very frustrating, can't you call it by the function it fulfills? (e.g. created_time) instead of the data type it holds?

Answer (score 0):

**For MySQL**

The example you are following is for a date, not a complete timestamp. For those strings you will need `str_to_date` and you will need to memorize `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f'` because every time you run a query against that table you are going to need it. A far better solution would be to use a REAL datetime column.  [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6283b/1)

```
select
      `datetime`
    , str_to_date(`datetime`,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f')
    , plugin_name  
from plugin_names 
where str_to_date(`datetime`,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f') > '2017-10-29T06:16:49.426000' 
and str_to_date(`datetime`,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f') < '2017-12-29T06:16:49.314000'
```

Just wait until some enters in invalid date into that column.... e.g.

```
'2O17-02-30T00:44:48.53000'
```

*and it isn't what you think it is*